# Can a string be padded to match a regular expression?

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm facing an optimization problem in a program that searches files whose path match a given regular expression (PCRE). Typical expressions could be:

```
^C:\test\(a|b)\foo\bar
^C:\test\[^\\]+\foo
^C:\test\.*\foo
```

Right now the implementation detects the constant prefix path ("C:\test\"), only enumerates this directory and applies the regex on all path names.

Looking at the first example, there might be a folder "c" in C:\test\ that contains a million files. None of these can possibly match the regex, but they are still enumerated. Therefore, before enumerating the directory, I would like to check whether it is at all possible to append something to the path so that it would match the regex.

**Generally speaking**: Is it possible to decide (efficiently), whether a given string can be concatenated with at least one suffix to match a given regular expression?

It is clear that cases like the third example are impossible to optimize, but in many other cases this would save a lot of execution time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered splitting the regex on path separators and only applying the portion of the regex that applies at the current depth of your search? This seems like a much more efficient way of proceeding.

Comment: I agree with @tvanfosson; you should check directory entries as you descend to prevent unnecessary directory listing.  So, for example, in `C:\test`, you would check *only* the children of that directory.  If any of the matches are subdirectories, you can descend into them, and run your next regular expression on its children, and so on.